# Selecting parent list with child in CSS

Tags: css

I want to keep hover color on parent list, when child list is hovered.

Here's example where second menu has submenus and when you hover over submenus, color of main menu is gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/ya8ga/

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="menu2">
<ul>
    <li class="l1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l2 dropDown"><a href="#">Hotel</a>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li class="l1"><a href="#">Hotel Sub 1</a></li>
            <li class="l2"><a href="#">Hotel Sub 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possibly not related, but you aren't closing your internal `<ul>` or it's second `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
#menu2 li a:hover{background:#89E00C; color:#2D1C13;}
```

to this:

```
#menu2 li:hover{background:#89E00C; color:#2D1C13;}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Nice, i had to do some remodeling, but basically this works great. Thank you